# website gets slow when huge amount of data is being loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a internal team website build using python django and `angularJS`. The website works fine when there is low data/ content on it.
When the website gets scrolled and more data is loaded. It becomes slow.
The major problem occurs when we try to open any `modal` or try to write text in the `textarea`. The text lags while writing and `modal` open very slowly.

I have used nested `ng-repeat` there are 5 nested `ng-repeat`.

```html
<div ng-repeat="x in xyz">
  <div ng-repeat="y in xyz">
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="img in xyz">
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="y in xyz">
    <div ng-repeat="z in xyz">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above is the  example of the structure being used in the website.
The above snippet repeat itself around 100 times thorughout the page.
These are having images, forms, text, input , user tagging like facebook.
ngCacheBuster,ui.bootstrap, ngTagsInput, ui.mention,monospaced.elastic these are the external library being used in the website.
the website is built using bootstrap.
Is there a specific reason why the website becomes heavy. 
each size of the image is around 100kb on an average.

Comment: This question is too broad. From just your description, several possible performance impacts come to mind. This ranges from missing DB indexes to AngularJS issues to too many large images. Also, you have not mentioned whether you find it slow in development or in production mode. Note that in development mode, collectstatic has not run and CSS/JS resources have not been minified, and caches are not in effect. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ might help for production issues.

Answer (score 0):

really? the page loads slow when there is alot of data? :D

anyway the most simple method to speed-up heavy data apps is to conditionally load and render parts of it, for example:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in bla" ng-click="showL1 = true">
    <div ng-repeat="y in boo" ng-if="showL1  === true">
        //more...
    </div>
</div>
```

on the other part is double check your architecture, since there is a very limited amount of data a person can take from a page and therefor start thinking about tabs and paging

Comment: no the page do not load slow.
once the page is fully loaded. then doing some action on the page is very tedious. Like typing text or opening any modal

Comment: are you sure the page really completed? sounds like some extra background things going there. test yourself with dev toos -> profiler

Comment: yeah nothing is running in the background.
Is there some effect of the watcher on the page ??